# Which option for 4 players cards game

Tags: android

I am designing a cards game for android that is played by 4 players (3 bots and 1 human)
I am wondering about the right approach to do this taking into consideration UI and game calculations.
Below are two ways, which one would be better?

1- Start a thread  (or assignTask) that would loop through all the players and update screen accordignly

```
void doInBackground(){

   for (i=0;i<13;i++){
     player1.play();
     //update GUI
     thread.sleep(1000);
     player2.play();
     //update GUI
     thread.sleep(1000);
     player3.play();
     //update GUI
     thread.sleep(1000);
     player4.play();
     //update GUI
     thread.sleep(1000);

   }

}
```

2- Second options is to have the looping running on backgroud thread but the calculation of each player is in a thread

```
void OnCreat(){

.
.
.
.
   for (i=0;i<13;i++){
     new thread().execute(player1.play());
     new thread().execute(player2.play();
     new thread().execute(player3.play();
     new thread().execute(player4.play();


   }

}
```

I am thinking the first option would be better just because I dont have to make sure that no player 2 does not play before player 1 and plus I can us thread.sleep() in between plays (to give a pause between plays).

Any thoughts ? Or even better ideas?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the first option. because it seems so that in your game, players play one by one.